# Multi inputs which user can only enter in one of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Consider a form which has many inputs, the inputs each has an radio button associated with them. User selects a radio and the associated input will be displayed.

http://jsfiddle.net/0uL6zzja/

If the number of inputs increase (for example 15) we will end up with lots of boilerplate code in js of all radio buttons ( they all do the same thing, disable other inputs, enable my input)

The js is as:

```
$('#precentRadio').change(function () {
    $("#dolorsInput").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#precentInput").attr("disabled", false);
})
$('#dolorsRadio').change(function () {
    $("#precentInput").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#dolorsInput").attr("disabled", false);
})
```

Are there any way which can can minimize the code ?!

Comment: Yes there is. Use a class name instead of writing out lots code with different IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0uL6zzja/1/)

Use a class name for the buttons that trigger the inputs to disable/enable, and a class name for the inputs. Disable them all, and enable the one you want by traversing from the clicked button to the closest `.input-group` then back down to the input field.

jQuery (this is all)

```
$('.some-button').change(function () {
    $('.some-input').prop("disabled", true);
    $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.some-input').prop("disabled", false);
})
```

HTML

```
Please enter amount in "$" or "%":<p/>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="input-group"> 
        <span class="input-group-addon">
                 <input name="switched" checked="checked" type="radio" class="some-button">
        </span> 
        <div class="input-group input-group-applyed-input-manager">
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            <input class="form-control some-input" type="text" >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="input-group"> 
        <span class="input-group-addon">
                 <input name="switched" type="radio" class="some-button">
        </span> 
        <div class="input-group input-group-applyed-input-manager">
            <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
            <input class="form-control some-input" type="text" disabled>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

(repeat)
```

Also `disabled="true"` isn't correct, it's not a boolean value in HTML, it's either there or not there, and you should use `.prop()` not `attr()` for disabled.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning prop()

Comment: Thanks for (+1)! This works prefect even if we have other inputs which do not have any radio button with them, as in this demo http://jsfiddle.net/0uL6zzja/4/.

Comment: Do you think we can enhance js to avoid inputs having their own class, some thing like @Rory McCrossan answer

Comment: They already have a class anyway but use whatever you think works best and is easiest to understand, to search for the elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a common class to your radio buttons and attach a single event to all of them. From there you can use DOM traversal to only change the related text input. Something like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="input-group"> 
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <input name="switched" class="input-toggle" checked="checked" type="radio" />
        </span> 
        <div class="input-group input-group-applyed-input-manager"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.input-toggle').change(function() {
    $('.input-group input[type="text"]').prop('disabled', true); // disable all
    $(this).closest('.input-group').find('input[type="text"]').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0uL6zzja/2/)

Comment: This is prefect idea. But please see http://jsfiddle.net/mtmh5db1/ If there is another input group in the form (with no radio button) the script will disable that too! Is there any way we can update the selector that to avoid this?!

Answer (score 1):

Sure. The correct way to associate radio buttons with a similar function is to use a common `name` rather than a `class`. This makes the radio buttons mutually exclusive (so only one of the options in the group can be active at once).

Then, add the jQuery `.change` handler not to a single item but to all the radio buttons with that name `$('input:radio[name=whatever]').change( ... );`.

Inside the function, it is easy to write code which enables the text field directly following the radio button that was clicked, using jQuery's `next()` method, and disables all other text fields that follow other radio buttons in the group.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the HTML, but the `id`s of the radio buttons and inputs will continue to match (`xxxRadio` and `xxxInput`), you can handle things by looking up the `id` of the selected radio button, and enabling the respective input:

```js
$('input[name=switched]').change(
  function() {
    var selected = $('input[name=switched]:checked');
    var selId = selected.attr('id');
    var inpId = '#' + selId.replace(/Radio$/, 'Input');
    var activeInput = $(inpId);
    
    $('input.form-control').prop('disabled' ,true);
    activeInput.prop('disabled', false);
  }
);
```

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
 div.input-group > div.input-group > span.input-group-addon {
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Please enter amount in "$" or "%":<p/>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="input-group"> 
        <span class="input-group-addon">
     <input name="switched" checked="checked" type="radio" id="dolorsRadio">
  </span> 
        <div class="input-group input-group-applyed-input-manager">
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="dolorsInput">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="input-group"> 
        <span class="input-group-addon">
     <input name="switched" type="radio" id="precentRadio">
  </span> 
        <div class="input-group input-group-applyed-input-manager">
            <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="precentInput" disabled="true">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```